# Como saber se o scrollbar está ativo e seu tamanho?

Tags: javascript, rolamento

Tenho um menu que é aberto baseado nas coordenadas `X` e `Y` do `click`, porém ao ser aberto nas extremidades ele acabava extrapolando o layout, arrumei isso, mas quando o `scrollbar` lateral está ativo ele acaba extrapolando alguns pixels (provavelmente no `height` também), pois o `window.innerWidth` não tira a diferença do tamanho do scroll, exemplo...

quando o scroll não está ativo `window.innerWidth = 1420`

quando o scroll está ativo `window.innerWidth = 1420`

Ou seja, dependendo da plataforma o scroll em média pode ter uma largura de até 15/20px, preciso detectar quando o Scrollbar está ativo e quando ativo saber seu tamanho para subtrair essa diferença, é possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Saber se tem *scroll*

Para descobrir se a janela tem *scroll* basta comparar a altura do documento  com o tamanho da janela.

Veja esse código e modifique a altura da `div` para ver que identifica quando tem `scroll`:

```js
let doc = $(document).height();
let win = $(window).height();

if(doc > win){
  console.log('Tem scroll');
} else {
  console.log('Não tem scroll');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-color: lightgreen; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Caso queira com JavaScript puro:

```js
let body = document.body, html = document.documentElement;

let docHeight = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);

let winHeight = window.innerHeight;

if (docHeight > winHeight){
  console.log('Tem Scroll');
} else {
  console.log('Não tem Scroll');
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: lightgreen; height: 100px;"></div>
```

## Obter a largura do *scroll*

Através dessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382516/getting-scroll-bar-width-using-javascript) vi que é possível criar uma `div` escondida, outra `div` dentro dela com *scroll* e através da diferença das duas saber qual é a largura do *scroll* utilizado pelo navegador.

Esse é o código:

```js
function getScrollbarWidth() {
    var outer = document.createElement("div");
    outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
    outer.style.width = "100px";
    outer.style.msOverflowStyle = "scrollbar"; // needed for WinJS apps

    document.body.appendChild(outer);

    var widthNoScroll = outer.offsetWidth;
    // force scrollbars
    outer.style.overflow = "scroll";

    // add innerdiv
    var inner = document.createElement("div");
    inner.style.width = "100%";
    outer.appendChild(inner);        

    var widthWithScroll = inner.offsetWidth;

    // remove divs
    outer.parentNode.removeChild(outer);

    return widthNoScroll - widthWithScroll;
}

console.log(getScrollbarWidth());
```

Comment: Legal, o difícil vai ser como conseguirei achar o tamanho do scroll, na verdade acho que vou ter de setar um estilo para ele com css3 e deixar esse tamanho fixo

Comment: Coloquei a outra metade da resposta.

Comment: Consegui resolver com seguinte propriedade scrollWidth e scrollHeight em document.body, ela calcula o innerWidht/Height da página retirando o tamanho do scroll caso esteja ativo, era tudo que eu precisava...